# React router v6 easiest way to access params outside route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
<Menu/>

<Routes>
<Route path="/" element={<HomeView />} />
<Route path="/website/:Id" element={<WebsiteView />} />
</Routes>
```

What is the easiest way to access Id parameter from Menu component?

UseParams can only be used in element rendered by route.

I am currently doing this:

```
const location = useLocation();

const Id = location.pathname.split("/")[2]
```

This is however not rigid enough for me I think. I want the react way of retrieving the Id Param please - no fancy solutions please, the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [matchPath](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/matchPath):

react-router v6:

```
const match = matchPath({ path: "/users/:id" }, "/users/123");
```

react-router v5:

```
const match = matchPath("/users/123", {
  path: "/users/:id",
  exact: true,
  strict: false
});
```

Comment: many thanks, this works - could you possible explain a little bit please? What are the parameters and how does it work.

Comment: Also this returns the paremter you specify, not what is in the url in the browser. I want the paremter in the url that the user has been sent to.

Comment: Can you update my example to understand what you want to do. https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-heisenberg-6lzzs?file=/src/index.js

Comment: yep i have done that now.

Comment: Okay so I just had to put the location.pathname as the second parameter, which I didn't know. So what matchPath does is check if the url matches the specified path I have given. if it does it return the details about that path including the param object which contains id. Many thanks my friend!

Answer (score 3):

The `id` route match param is only available on the `params` object of all ancestor and descendent `Route` components within a `Routes` component.

If the `Menu` component is capable of using the `useParams` hook (*and there's a way to inject `params` as a prop if `Menu` is a class component*) there is a refactor you can do where `Menu` is rendered as part of a layout along with an `Outlet` component and it will then be in the route hierarchy to access the route params.

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    element={
      <>
        <Menu />   // <-- descendent route match params accessible here
        <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes rendered here
      </>
    }
  >
    <Route path="/" element={<HomeView />} />
    <Route path="/website/:Id" element={<WebsiteView />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Example `Menu` component:

```
const Menu = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  console.log("Menu", params);
  return ...;
};
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-easiest-way-to-access-params-outside-route]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which way is more optimal or is it just a matter of preference? Also after reading docs on outlet I am not sure what the purpose of outlet is?

Comment: @mycodegoesKABOOM `Outlet`s allow you to easily nest routes for the most part. IMO I think my solution is slightly more optimal only for the reason that you don't need to declare the path a second time in `Menu` just to get the param. In fact, with this solution `Menu` has access to all the route params under the layout. I think it would partly come down to preference and familiarity.

Comment: Many thank Drew - I am trying to push myself to implement solution that are not just to my liking. Whilst the first solution seems simpler to me, I can understand slightly the benefit of your solution and will try to understand it better so I can implement. With menu having access to more than just a matched params does seem like a good benefit.

Answer (score -1):

react-router v6: The most easiest way to get an id from url. Caution(This only works if your component is a child of a  componentThis only works if your component is a child of a  component)

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
const { id } = useParams();

return(
    <>
        <h2> This is useParams id = {id} </h2>
    </>
);
```

Comment: This only works if your component is a child of a `<Route>` component.